# TypeScript: TSC turn of output of hints

Tags: typescript, tsconfig

Is there anyway to turn of the hints that are generated when running TSC?
I have spent a good 30 minutes looking through the documentation for tsconfig files and I cannot find anything that jumps out at me for controlling the hints being generated. I would prefer that I just see errors and warnings.

Edit: Added terminal output for example/and tsconfig.json

```json
{
    "extends": "@tsconfig/svelte/tsconfig.json",
    "include": ["src/**/*.d.ts", "src/**/*.ts","src/**/.svelte", "src/vite-env.d.ts"],
    "exclude": ["node_modules/*", "public/*"],
    "compilerOptions": {                       
        "baseUrl": ".",                  
        "esModuleInterop": true ,
        "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true ,
        "importHelpers": true,
        "lib": ["dom", "ESNext"],
        "module": "ESNext",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "noUnusedLocals": false,
        "importsNotUsedAsValues": "preserve",
        "skipLibCheck": true ,
        "strict": true ,
        "target": "ESNext"
    }
}
```

```
c:\Users\bwilliams\Repositories\Learning\LicenseWebTool\src\scripts\CreateInputForm.ts:32:9
Hint: JSDoc types may be moved to TypeScript types.
        */
        static Input(type:string, name:string, value:string)
        {
```

Comment: What "hints" are you seeing and where?  Generally I don't interpret tsc output as having "hints" but maybe we are using different terminology.  Could you provide a [mre] that demonstrates your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE?

Comment: @jcalz I updated the prompt

Comment: Thanks, but I can't use that to reproduce the issue.  If you can provide a [mre] then I might be more able to diagnose.